# AWS EMR cluster stucked starting with custom AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, amazon-ami

I'm trying to run a EMR cluster with custom AMI because the bootstrap time take 13 minutes. I have created an AMI from a m5.large instances with all of the software installed. This instances is based on amazon linux 2 AMI. I have created the image (clicking in action, image, create image). When I run the cluster it starts the instances on EC2 but the cluster keeps on starting.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Was the instance running when you created the image? I had the same/similar issue on AL2 with regular instances. Solution was to make image when the instance was in the stopped state.

Comment: I have tried again with the instance stopped. I got the same results. I'm using emr 5.30.1 version. Maybe it's a problerm with this version?